# How to search by genre in Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, mp3

I've got a bunch of mp3s.  Each album is a folder which is named after the artist.

I am trying to search through all of them to find a particular genre, which is contained in the mp3 tags.

So far I've got this in my search bar:

`grime kind:=music tags:genre`

However it is not producing any results.  I don't know why.  I've tried adding in the equels as in the 'kind' like so:

`grime kind:=music tags:=genre` but it is not working either.

Anyone got any ideas?  I know this is doable with lots of other third party programs but damn it Windows 10 should be able to do this native by now.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so once I optimised the folder to 'Music' and applied to the root folder and all subfolders:

[image]

I then got the option to do this:

`kind:=music genre:Grime`

[image]

So its not `tags`.  It's simply `genre`.